# How to print array index when using random()

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm having issues with my code. It's supposed to populate an array list with 5 words. A random number is then generated and used to pick a word from the array list based on its index. The problem I'm having is when I try to print the random number it doesn't match the index of the word displayed.

```
/*This program will prompt the user to enter 5 words.
These messages will be stored in a ArrayList.
The program will then number the messages and display them in a list.
The program will then generate a random number.
The program will then use the random number to display a word from the ArrayList.*/

package wordup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class WordUp {

/* @param args the command line arguments */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here 

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word.");
        words.add(i, input.nextLine());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println((i)+". "+words.get(i)); //Should print the messages
    }

    Random word = new Random();
    int index = word.nextInt(words.size());
    System.out.println("Your randomly generated word is: " +words.get(word.nextInt(words.size()))+".");
    System.out.println("It was found at index " +index+".");
}   

}
```

For example, the output I get is:

```
run:
Enter a word.
a
Enter a word.
b
Enter a word.
c
Enter a word.
d
Enter a word.
e

0. a
1. b
2. c
3. d
4. e

Your randomly generated word is: c.
It was found at index 0.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: Each time you call `Random.nextInt()`, it generates another random value. In this example you call `word.nextInt()` twice: once to assign to `index` and once to select word. That explains why selected word doesn't match index.

Comment: What would I need to change to get it to print the number used to select word?

Comment: `System.out.println("Your randomly generated word is: " +words.get(index)+".");`

Comment: Thank you!, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Your print line should be as follows.

```
    int index = word.nextInt(words.size());
    System.out.println("Your randomly generated word is: " + words.get(index) + ".");
```

You find the index just before the print. So you can use it inside the print line. No need to find it again when printing...